# How can I randomize a picture under a cover in actionscript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, random, flash-cs5

I'm making a flash game for practice and I have my stage set up so there are 9 boxes. When the game is started, one of the boxes is randomized as the one with the start underneath, if you pick the box with the star underneath, you win.

The randomizing code is

```
var star = 1 + Math.Round(Math.Random()*8.0)//generate a number between 1 and 9
```

What i dont know is how to attach this code so that it assigns the star to one of my 9 boxes made as buttons. How can I hide the star underneath the box as a cover.
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm picturing one of those games where you but a ball under one of three cups and swap the cups, then guess which one has the ball.

The simplest way to hide one object under another is to just add it to the stage before the object covering it. So add your star to the stage, then add all your boxes. BUT since you don't have to have an unseen object actually be on the stage, I recommend not adding the star to the stage until it is revealed, and remove it when it gets hidden again.

You can create layers to make sure objects are always above/below what they need to be above/below. Create sprite objects, and call them layers. Add them in order from bottom to top. Add other sprites to these layer sprites to control their display order.

```
var layer1:Sprite = new Sprite(); // Bottom / background
var layer2:Sprite = new Sprite(); // Top / foreground

stage.addChild(layer1);
stage.addChild(layer2);


layer2.addChild(someObject1);
layer1.addChild(someObject2); // someObject2 will be below someObject1
```

That deals with covering the star with the boxes.

You can put your boxes in an array. You'll want a number between 0 and 8, then just use that as the index in the array to get the box you want.

```
var whichBox:int = (int)(Math.random() * 9);
var boxesArray:Array = new Array();
for (var i:int = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    boxesArray.push(new Box()); // Or whatever your boxes are
}
var boxWithStar:Box = boxesArray[whichBox];
```

You can then move the star to the same location as its box...

```
star.x = boxWithStar.x;
star.y = boxWithStar.y;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty handy function you can use:

```
function randRange(start:Number, end:Number) : Number
{
   return Math.floor(start +(Math.random() * (end - start)));
}
```

example (any number between 0 - 9) :

```
var random:int = randRange(0,9);
```

remember to make it an int or you may end up with a float.